# The property 'Content' is set more than once - XAML

Tags: xamarin

Every time i try to implement `<maps:Map IsShowingUser="True" x:Name="Mapa" />` in my mainPage show's "The property 'Content' is set more than once". Every time I put in this place gives me 'The property 'Content' is set more than once'.

If anyone could explain in simple terms where the Content property is set that would be most helpful.

```
<ContentPage xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Class="Pap.MainPage">

    <maps:Map IsShowingUser="True" x:Name="Mapa" />

    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="Main">
        
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="main" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image Source="C:\Users\david\Desktop\Pap\Pap\Pap.Android\Resources\drawable\User.png" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Image>

        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="body" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
   Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0">
            <!--<StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Red">
    <Label Text="Titulo" />
    
   </StackLayout>-->
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label Text="Slider-Example"  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Image Source="C:\Users\david\Desktop\Pap\Pap\Pap.Android\Resources\drawable\User.png" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Handle_Tapped">
                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContentPage` has an implicit `Content` property that can contain a **single** child element.  If you want to include more than one piece of content on your page, you need to use a [Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts) container, like a `StackLayout`

```
<ContentPage ... >
  <StackLayout>
    ... multiple children can go here
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

if you were using C# instead of XAML, you would explicitly set the `Content` property

```
myPage.Content = new StackLayout{ ... };
```